# Do I need to store the list before using foreach?

Tags: c#, foreach

[MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) shows this:

```
    // Open the file to read from. 
    string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    foreach (string s in readText)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

But I'm thinking this:

```
    // Open the file to read from. 
    foreach (string s in File.ReadAllLines(path))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between those two code snippets, assuming that `readText` is never used anywhere else.

Even in the second case, the results of the method call will end up being stored *somewhere*, even if that location doesn't have some name that you can refer to in your code.

On a side note, if you're going to do nothing but iterate through the lines, you can use `ReadLines` instead of `ReadAllLines` to stream the lines of text, rather than eagerly loading the entire file into memory before processing any of the lines.  This prevents a long delay before accessing the first line, can provide a substantial speed improvement in the event that you end up exiting the loop before processing all lines (keep in mind that this can happen due to exceptions, in addition to explicitly exiting the loop), and dramatically reduces the memory footprint of the program even if you do end up processing all of the lines.

Answer (score 2):

The two code snippets are equivalent.

Better still, if you're paying by character, there is no need to be explicit about the type of s:

```
foreach (var s in File.ReadAllLines(path))
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: Lol, +1 for paying by character.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to store the result in a list if the list is not needed at a later time.
My guess is that the compiler will optimize this anyway when building in Release mode.

However, there is one advantage of the first approach: during debugging, you can use the "Auto" or "Locals" window to inspect the content of the variables, which might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` operation is performed on result of `File.ReadAllLines(path)` method. So they both are same.